# IE10 not applying CSS styles on HTML5's header/footer/nav/main elements outside of JSFiddle. HTML5 quirks mode triggering?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, element, quirks-mode

I'm having issues with IE10 applying CSS styles I've specified for HTML5 elements (and their children when targeting the child using the HTML5 element tag name in the selector), so I broke it down into a simpler example and put together a simple [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4NmBR/1/) to demonstrate the issue, but when I tested the JSFiddle, IE10 decided to apply the styles properly. So, I took the exact source code of the JSFiddle's resulting iframe, and copied it into [a file hosted on my server](http://play.olhblogspot.com/html5.html) and alas it failed to properly apply the styles once again.

JSFiddle's source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <style type='text/css'>
    header, nav, main, footer {
        display: block;
        background: gray;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 1px;
    }
    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
}//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x80&text=Logo" />
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>    
    <p>This is filler content inside the <code>&lt;main&gt;</code> element. The <code>&lt;header&gt;</code>, <code>&lt;main&gt;</code> and <code>&lt;footer&gt;</code> should each have a gray background and be displayed as a block.</p>
</main>
<footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2013, All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

What's the deal with IE10? It can't possibly be the code, since it works fine in an iframe, or do iframes get the same treatment as their parent page?

What's causing IE10 to trip up here? Could it possibly be something server related? That doesn't make much sense, but this is an odd one.

Naturally, any fixes would surely be appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, viewing the JSFiddle's source in its own window still looks good, which makes me think it's a server thing, but that just doesn't make any sense. Why would that happen?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/4NmBR/1/show/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Developer tools it's running in IE8 mode on your server. Try adding this code to your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

You can also set this on your server:

**Apache:**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for refreshing my memory. Been a while since I've used this tag. Still curious how to set it up server-side though.

Comment: What kind of server are you using? I added instructions for Apache (.htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

Your web server has an "X-UA-Compatible" header set to "IE=8", which forces IE to IE8 document mode. You need to either remove it or set it to "edge".
If you don't have access to server settings you could try adding [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to your page which should allow you to style HTML5 elements in older IEs.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that could be set on the server side. Where should it be set? Your answer wasn't clear whether it was something that goes in an .htaccess file or elsewhere.

Comment: The headers can be set both in the server config or programmatically. 
In your case the header is already being set somewhere (to IE8) and I would advise you to find where this is done and update it.
Otherwise you are risking setting it in multiple places, which is going to be hard to debug.
The actual implementation depends on your server and server version.
I have only done it in IIS, obviously you are using Apache, but it may be useful for someone else:

`Response.Headers.Add("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge,chrome=1");`
`Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge,chrome=1");`